# QGIS raster merge results in a black rectangle

Tags: qgis, raster, srtm

I have 4 SRTM raster like this: [image]

I want to merge them into 1, but when I do this, something like this happens (I only tried it with two of them here):[image]

I also tried changing the min and max values that are here both 0 to the min and max values from the two used rasters but it doesn't change.
Do you have any idea what's the problem here and what I can do?

Here's the Log file:

> QGIS version: 3.8.0-Zanzibar QGIS code revision: 11aff65f10 Qt
>   version: 5.11.2 GDAL version: 2.4.1 GEOS version: 3.7.2-CAPI-1.11.0
>   b55d2125 PROJ version: Rel. 5.2.0, September 15th, 2018 Processing
>   algorithm… Algorithm 'Merge' starting… Input parameters: { 'DATA_TYPE'
>   : 5, 'INPUT' : ['C:/Users/.../srtm/eu_dem_v11_E30N20/eu_dem_v11_E30N20.TIF','C:/Users/.../srtm/eu_dem_v11_E30N30/eu_dem_v11_E30N30.TIF'],
>   'NODATA_INPUT' : None, 'NODATA_OUTPUT' : None, 'OPTIONS' : '',
>   'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'PCT' : False, 'SEPARATE' : False }
>
> GDAL command: python3 -m gdal_merge -ot Float32 -of GTiff -o
>   C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Temp/processing_0bf9ee3ec2f548829744a6bd244c96a2/60f16fc4e2394ab496e96b39dd323a73/OUTPUT.tif
>   --optfile C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Temp/processing_0bf9ee3ec2f548829744a6bd244c96a2/1eb95beda25545199dda413988a6c112/mergeInputFiles.txt
>   GDAL command output: 0Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in
>   _run_module_as_main
>
> "**main**", mod_spec)
>
> File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in
>   _run_code
>
> exec(code, run_globals)
>
> File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\bin\gdal_merge.py", line 611, in
>
> sys.exit(main())
>
> File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\bin\gdal_merge.py", line 596, in main
>
> fi.copy_into(t_fh, band, band, nodata)
>
> File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\bin\gdal_merge.py", line 343, in copy_into
>
> nodata_arg)
>
> File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\bin\gdal_merge.py", line 124, in
>   raster_copy
>
> m_band)
>
> File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\bin\gdal_merge.py", line 186, in
>   raster_copy_with_mask
>
> to_write = Numeric.choose(mask_test, (data_src, data_dst))
>
> File
>   "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py",
>   line 422, in choose
>
> return _wrapfunc(a, 'choose', choices, out=out, mode=mode)
>
> File
>   "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py",
>   line 56, in _wrapfunc
>
> return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
>
> MemoryError
>
> Execution completed in 941.61 seconds

Comment: Have you had a look at the histogramm for the merged layer? Have you made sure you choose the correct layers to merge? Have you changed any presets in the `merge`dialogue?

Comment: I chose the correct layers and I didn't change anything in the merge dialogue

Answer (score 4):

The merge was not successful:
towards the end of you log you can read:

`MemoryError`

I would assume (also looking at the shape of the output "map", and judging from the large amount of time it took) this could be due to a too large region setting.
Therefore, I would try setting a smaller output region and checking the required output resolution.

I downloaded two SRTM files, and merged them to take a screenshot which you hopefully find useful as a reference/comparison.

**Settings:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]